# How to add new procedure/function to package without deleting existing procedures?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is any possiblity to add new procedure/function to package without deleting exsiting procedures ? I can use `create or replace package body` but this statement delete existing procedures/functions in package.

My package will contain many functions/procedures (more than 200 lines) so keeping them in one file is bad idea, it would be very unreadable, so I want to keep each procedure/function in different files and just add them to package.

I found issue of five years before, where someone says it is impossible. 
I am asking because maybe somethink change since then or maybe exists better solution. What is the best idea to not have the clutter in functions/procedures ?

Comment: Not possible. The package body can only be specified in a single create statement. You can split that into multiple files unless you concatenate them to build a valid `create package body` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Maybe do you know other idea how to keep them without the mess ?

Comment: 200 lines is not big.  You could write the package as a wrapper that then calls individual pakcages/functions, but then that list will grow.

Comment: 200 lines is not big, Our code is esealy 10.000 lines per packages body. Just make sure you name the procedures and function properly, so that their name replesents their function. But to answer your question: No, It is still impossible.

Comment: I guess you could read your compiled package body from `user_source` view, insert it into a clob variable and somehow add you new procedure to that clob (being careful with the last `end;`, duplicate procedures...). Then `execute immediate` that clob variable. Seems overly complicated to me.

Comment: If the package is too big, it may be time to refactor it into several smaller packages. This same goes for any language (Java classes, Perl modules etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "add" procedures/functions to a package, any more than you "add" a line of code to an existing procedure. Instead, every change replaces the old version of the entire package with a new version of the entire package.

Instead, you should keep the entire package source (including the "create or replace package" bits) in a text file which you check into your version control repository, and always follow the following steps to change the package:

1. Edit the source file using your favourite code editor.
2. Run the script to compile the package on your database.
3. Test.
4. Checkin the source file to your version control repository.

This way, you never lose anything when you want to add something.